# check cookie value before loading page via registrybyId set href

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

I have a dijit tree that when a node is clicked it loads an html page in the center content page.  One of the html pages is a login page and I'd like to check a cookie to see if they have already logged on, so I can set the page appropriately if the page gets re-loaded.  Is there a way to check for a cookie on page load, or perhaps a better method than this?  Thanks

my code for the tree is:

```
 TOCSet: function (TOCStore) {
        var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
            store: TOCStore,
            query: { root: true }
        });

        // Create the Tree.
        var tree = new Tree({
            model: myModel,
            onClick: function (item, node, evt) {
                // Get the URL from the item, and navigate to it
                evt.preventDefault();
                var href = item.url;
                registry.byId('Content').set('href', href); //set the page on node clicks
            }

        });
        tree.placeAt("TOC");
        tree.startup();
        ready(function () {
            registry.byId("Content").set("href", "Login.htm");//set the login page at start
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the cookie using "dojo/cookie" after successful login

```
    function SetLoginCookie(lia) {
        cookie("LoggedInAs", lia);
    }
```

and then used "dojo/ready" to check for the cookie when the page reloads

```
ready(function () {
            var lia = cookie("LoggedInAs");
            alert(lia + " is logged in");
    });
```